# Chrome Extension API not firing onChanged event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am using `chrome.downloads.onChanged.addListener` to find out when a download completes.

The callback does not fire sometimes, and there is no apparent reason for it.

The code looks like this

```
chrome.downloads.onChanged.addListener(function (downloadDelta) {...});
```

and it is in `background.js` and file is mentioned in `background` section of manifest. I added `console.log(downloadDelta);` at the very begining of callback, but it is not fired.

The API is mentioned [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads)

EDIT: [Test extension](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1ealGW0r-JOeWIyMmV4TzFudTQ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hm. it looks like a bug  only if it is not fired *sometimes*

Comment: If you 're able to provide me with detail reproducible steps, I will debug it on chromium core.

Comment: A test extension is added to question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably this has to do with peculiarities of [Event pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) - something not working properly when your page gets unloaded.

This is easy to test - remove `"persistent": "false"` from the manifest.

That said, your test extension does not violate any Event page recommendations and [`chrome.downloads` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#event-onChanged) does not list any incompatibilities. Therefore, 2 scenarios are possible:

1. It's quite possible that you are misinterpreting results due to the page being unloaded. For instance, if the page gets unloaded between the callback executing and you opening the devtools for it - the console and all local state will be wiped.

   To test for that, make sure to write your diagnostics to persistent storage - [`chrome.storage` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) is one option for this.
2. If you are 100% sure the above is not the case, there may be a bug related to event pages and `chrome.downloads`. In that case, it should be reported.

Comment: The extension adds a download button to Google Play store, then tracks downloads using the callback. For possiblity 1, could it be because I click the download link, download starts and then I navigate away from page? Extension unloads in this situation, right? In that case, what can be done to prevent this behavior? Maybe use multiple tabs to start downloading, then closing the appropriate tab when download finished?

Comment: I removed `persistant` from manifest, and in last tests, the problem seems to be gone. I will test more, and report and accept answer later. Thank you!

Comment: It really depends on what your code does. It's impossible to say without seeing it. I explained that your test extension fails because console gets wiped.